# Can not import pydelay

Tags: python

I have a homework to solve a delay differential equation using two packages, ddeint and pydelay. The problem is, I can't import pydelay to my program. It keeps saying that it can't import weave from scipy.

```
In [1]: import pydelay
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c7b60806236e>", line 1, in <module> import pydelay

  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pydelay\__init__.py", line 9, in <module> from _dde23 import dde23

  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pydelay\_dde23.py", line 32, in <module> from scipy import weave

ImportError: cannot import name weave
```

I use Windows 10 64 bit with Python 2.7, I write my program in Spyder 3.1.4. I have installed numpy 1.13.0+mkl so that I can install ddeint 0.1.2. I also have installed scipy 0.19.1 and weave 0.16.0. From what I've read, the new version of scipy doesn't have weave in it, and pydelay use weave from scipy, so I assume that my problem comes from that.

Is there any way for me to use pydelay with separated weave I've installed?

Comment: Start by showing us your actual error.  We can work better with that than with your summary.

Comment: You can install a specific version of a package with `pip install <package>==<version>`

Comment: Edit that into your question, and the exact line that you typed into the IPython console.  :-)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Done :) Hope it will be much clear than before.

Comment: @dashiell I've tried to install the older version of scipy (0.18.1) but the installation was fail.